# Adding a CUSTOM POST TYPE to a Wordpress site doesn't include all the options the theme has in other POST TYPES

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, custom-post-type

I am using a theme for my Wordpress site:

THEME:
https://themeforest.net/item/prague-architecture-and-interior-design-wordpress-theme/19618927

Site:
[RainProPixel.com](http://RainProPixel.com)

The theme has several post types, but I would like to add more.

I've added a new one called "Training" to "Post-type.php":

```
 <?php
/*
 * Portfolio post type.
 */

function register_custom_post_type() {

    $services_url_slug = cs_get_option('services_url_slug') ? cs_get_option('services_url_slug') : 'services-item';
    $services_category_slug = cs_get_option('services_category_slug') ? cs_get_option('services_category_slug') : 'services-category';

    // New Post Type
    register_post_type( 'services',
      array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Services','prague-plugins'),
            'singular_name' => esc_html__( 'Service','prague-plugins')
        ), 
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', ),
        'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'assets/repairing.png' , __FILE__ ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => $services_url_slug),
      )
    );
    // New Taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
      'service-category',
      'services',
      array(
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Categories','prague-plugins'),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $services_category_slug ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
      )
    );

    $training_url_slug = cs_get_option('training_url_slug') ? cs_get_option('training_url_slug') : 'training-item';
    $training_category_slug = cs_get_option('training_category_slug') ? cs_get_option('training_category_slug') : 'training-category';
    
    register_post_type( 'training',
      array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Training','prague-plugins'),
            'singular_name' => esc_html__( 'Training','prague-plugins')
        ), 
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', ),
        'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'assets/repairing.png' , __FILE__ ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => $training_url_slug),
      )
    );
    // New Taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
      'training-category',
      'training',
      array(
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Categories','prague-plugins'),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $training_category_slug ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
      )
    );

    // New Post Type
    $projects_url_slug = cs_get_option('projects_slug') ? cs_get_option('projects_slug') : 'projects-item';
    $projects_category_url_slug = cs_get_option('projects_category_slug') ? cs_get_option('projects_category_slug') : 'projects-category';

    register_post_type( 'projects',
      array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Projects','prague-plugins'),
            'singular_name' => esc_html__( 'Project','prague-plugins')
        ), 
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail' ),
        'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'assets/projects.png' , __FILE__ ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => $projects_url_slug),
      )
    );
    // New Taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
      'projects-category',
      'projects',
      array(
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Categories','prague-plugins'),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $projects_category_url_slug ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
      )
    );

    // New Post Type
    register_post_type( 'books',
      array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Books','prague-plugins'),
            'singular_name' => esc_html__( 'Book','prague-plugins')
        ), 
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail' ),
        'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'assets/agenda.png' , __FILE__ ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'books-item'),
      )
    );
    // New Taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
      'books-category',
      'books',
      array(
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Categories','prague-plugins'),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'books-category' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
      )
    );

    // New Post Type
    register_post_type( 'media',
      array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Media','prague-plugins'),
            'singular_name' => esc_html__( 'Media item','prague-plugins')
        ), 
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail' ),
        'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'assets/magazine.png' , __FILE__ ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'media-item'),
      )
    );
    
    // New Taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
      'media-category',
      'media',
      array(
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Categories','prague-plugins'),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'media-category' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
      )
    );

    // New Post Type
    register_post_type( 'exihibitions',
      array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Exihibitions','prague-plugins'),
            'singular_name' => esc_html__( 'Exihibition','prague-plugins')
        ), 
        'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'assets/museum.png' , __FILE__ ),
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail' ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'exihibitions-item'),
      )
    );

    
    // New Taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
      'exihibitions-category',
      'exihibitions',
      array(
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Categories','prague-plugins'),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'exihibitions-category' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
      )
    );

}

add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_post_type', 0);
```

The post type shows up in my Wordpress Admin Menu:

[Wordpress Admin Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNUo5.png)

I can create new posts:

[Creating A New Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YKzk.png)

My problem is that other POST TYPES that came with the theme have an additional set of options that I need to be able to edit also, called "Service Options":

[Service Options as seen on other post type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IngXj.png)

The DIV ID for it is called, "service_post_options" and I can't find where that's created on the site.

[DIV ID in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcuuU.png)

Does anyone have any clue what I'm missing here to make the new post type match the ones that came with the theme?

Answer (score 1):

For creating custom post type:

/ custom posttype /

```
       function my_first_custom_post_type() {
    
    // Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Producten', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Producten', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Producten', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Producten', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Producten', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'View Producten', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Producten', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Producten', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Producten', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search Producten', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'not_found' => __( 'Not Found', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'twentythirteen' ),
    );
    
    // Set other options for Custom Post Type
    
    $args = array(
    'label' => __( 'Producten', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'description' => __( 'Producten news and reviews', 'twentythirteen' ),
    'labels' => $labels,
    // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
    // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy.
    'taxonomies' => array( 'genres' ),
    /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
    * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
    * is like Posts.
    */
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'can_export' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    );
    
    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'Producten', $args );
    
    }
/* Hook into the 'init' action so that the function
* Containing our post type registration is not
* unnecessarily executed.
*/

add_action( 'init', 'my_first_custom_post_type', 0 );
```

Here I have created a custom post in the name of "Producten". It worked for me , try it out.